# Is it mandatory to have the EXPOSE command within the Dockerfile to expose ports

Tags: dockerfile

Is it mandatory to have the EXPOSE command within the Dockerfile to expose ports or is it good enough to pass it in the run command itself as an argument

```
FROM node:8

EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json index.js ./
RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```